# How to use setValue for useForm hook for creating form for edit page (REACT, javaScript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, use-form

Hi I have created components for Book Management System like Displaybooks, Addbooks, which are working fine, I have created below component for editing existing books:

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { Bookcontext } from "../bookcontext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const Editbook = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const { ISBN } = useParams();
  const books = useContext(Bookcontext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [book, setBook] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const book1 = books.find((b) => b.ISBN == ISBN);
    setBook(book1);
  }, []);

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const index = books.indexOf(books.find((b) => b.ISBN === ISBN));
    books.splice(index, 1, data);
    navigate("/display");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input
          type="number"
          {...register(
            "ISBN",
            /*('ISBN', { ISBN: book.ISBN}),*/ { required: true }
          )}
        />

        <input type="text" {...register("title", { required: true })} />

        <input type="text" {...register("author", { required: true })} />

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Editbook;
```

This is also working and the books are getting editted however I want to setValue of current book in the input tag with `('ISBN', { ISBN: book.ISBN}),` But this is not working so I have commented it for now.

Can you explain how to do this for all 3 inputs.

I am expecting current book values in the text areas that I can edit and submit:

Comment: I think you can set the value as default value

eg:- <input type="text" defaultValue={book.ISBN} {...register("title", { required: true })} />

Comment: Sorry, there is one change, I put title instead of the ISBN.

<input type="text" defaultValue={book.ISBN} {...register("ISBN", { required: true })} />

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value as default value like this.

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={book.ISBN} {...register("ISBN", { required: true })} />
```